# Critical temperature for an ideal gas

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

What is the critical temperature for an ideal gas? It can't be found from Andrew's isotherm as it is for real gases and states critical temperature as $\frac{8a}{27 R \cdot b}$, but for ideal gases $a = b = 0$.

Comment: The point is that ideal gasses *don't* have a critical temperature; by being composed of infinitesimal, completely non-interacting point particles, they are not subject to intermolecular interactions and phase changes. That's what makes them *ideal*, i.e. *simple*.

Comment: Thus they cant be liquified?

Comment: Sure enough, they can't.